# AWS boto3 -- Difference between `batch_writer` and `batch_write_item`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm currently applying boto3 with dynamodb, and I noticed that there are two types of batch write

`batch_writer` is used in tutorial, and it seems like you can just iterate through different JSON objects to do insert (this is just one example, of course)

`batch_write_items` seems to me is a dynamo-specific function. However, I'm not 100% sure about this, and I'm not sure what's the difference between these two functions (performance, methodology, what not)

Do they do the same thing? If they are, why having 2 different functions? If they're not, what's the difference? How's the performance comparison?

Comment: Dynamo API has the `BatchWriteItem` and Boto (a wrapper for the Dynamo API) just named it `batch_writer`. It's the same thing that was renamed in Boto.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand and use these APIs, with the batch_write_item(), you can even handle the data for more than one table in one query. But with batch_writer(), it means you are going to specify the actions are only applicable for a certain table. I think that should be the very basic difference I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

> `batch_writer` creates a context manager for writing objects to Amazon
>   DynamoDB in batch.
>
> The batch writer will automatically handle buffering and sending items
>   in batches.
>
> In addition, the batch writer will also automatically handle any
>   unprocessed items and resend them as needed. All you need to do is
>   call put_item for any items you want to add, and delete_item for any
>   items you want to delete.
>
> In addition, you can specify auto_dedup if the batch might contain
>   duplicated requests and you want this writer to handle de-dup for you.

[source](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/boto3-1.4.5/autoapi/dynamodb/table/index.html#dynamodb.table.TableResource.batch_writer)

Comment: `batch_writer` is the way to go--it's a higher level function that handles retries and so forth for you. `batch_write_item` is a thin wrapper around the underlying DynamoDB API. I put an example of `batch_writer` on GitHub: [https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/dynamodb/batching/dynamo_batching.py)